# ng-options selected data return object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a array of object `{ id:x, name: 's' }`  and using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to create drop down with default selected data. This is working fine so far.

Now when I select one of the option and see the selected data, it return complete object but i need only name field as well as default value must be selected on load.

```
// in controller
 vm.teams = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name:'First'
      },
       {
        id: 2,
        name:'Second'
      },
       {
        id: 3,
        name:'Third'
      }
    ];

    vm.teamFormData = {
        team: ''
    };

    vm.getTeam = function(formData) {
      $log.debug(formData); << here I get object
    }

// in View
<select ng-init="vm.teamFormData.team = vm.teams[0]"  
        ng-model="vm.teamFormData.team" 
        ng-options="t.name for t in vm.teams track by t.id" >
</select>
```

Here is my [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g0rnrVNy1tCzCkbwjUBr?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ngOptions` syntax is slightly off - it's `value as text for item in array`

```
ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in vm.teams track by t.id"
```

And your `ngInit` then becomes

```
ng-init="vm.teamFormData.team = vm.teams[0].name"
```

Side note - you probably don't want `ngInit` - there's no real use case in your above example for it. Instead, just set the property in the controller.

See plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7SGIdtfjucMnMqiEa7JY?p=preview

Comment: by doing this, i lost the default selected value. none is selected on load

Comment: you have added default data in formData bac in controller, can't we do it by `ngInit`?

Comment: @pro.mean -- You can - but `ngInit` isn't supposed to be used like that. Why do you want it like that rather than the controller?

Comment: just asking. Okay I will do it with controller. Kind;y update your answer with working plunker. so that i will accept it.